# What is the inverse Laplace of the given function?

Tags: calculus, inverse-laplace

$$\mathcal{L}^{- 1} \left( \frac{ (p + 1) e ^{- \pi / p}}{p ^ 2 + p + 1}\right) $$

I have already solved the question in which exponential power was $-\pi p$ instead of $-\frac{\pi}{p}$. The latter factor is disturbing me. I have also solved the whole part of the question except the exponential part.

But neither I know how to apply the shift theorem further nor find its Heaviside unit step function.

So, how should I proceed further?

Comment: Use MathJax, please, and show your attempt. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Now, a hint: complete the square in the denominator, and do some clever rewrites in the numerator. See here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/laplace_table.aspx

Comment: I think that  does not have finite closed-form expression in terms of very large class of special functions. You can expand by series at $p\to \infty$ and then get Inverse Laplace: $$\mathcal{L}_p^{-1}\left[\frac{(p+1) \exp \left(-\frac{\pi }{p}\right)}{p^2+p+1}\right](t)\approx 1-\pi  t+\frac{1}{4} \left(-2+\pi ^2\right) t^2+\frac{1}{36} \left(6+6 \pi -\pi ^3\right)
   t^3+\frac{1}{576} \left(-24 \pi -12 \pi ^2+\pi ^4\right) t^4+...$$

Comment: Since the author claims that he has already computed the inverse Laplace transform of $(p+1)/(p^2+p+1)$, which is indeed standard, I have provided the missing part for $e^{-a/p}$ ($a=\pi$ does not play a particular role in the problem).  It uses the Dirac mass and a Bessel function, and was inexplicably removed by three moderators.

Comment: Thanks everyone for giving your time. I appreciate it. Thanks @Sean Roberson.